# Translation to predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

We have a statement to be translated into first order logic (not caring whether it is true or false in the real world):
***There does not exist an even prime number which is the square of a prime number.***

I have trouble translating this sentence to first order logic. These were my steps:

$\forall y \neg \exists x ((prime(2*x) \land prime(y)) \implies (2*x=y*y))$
So, for all prime numbers y, there does not exist an even prime number that is equal to the square of the prime number y. So far, it should be correct.

$\forall y \neg \exists x (\neg(prime(2*x) \land prime(y)) \lor (2*x=y*y))$
Using laws for implication transformation, I changed the expression.

$\forall y \neg \exists x (\neg prime(2*x) \lor \neg prime(y) \lor (2*x=y*y))$
Using De Morgan laws, I changed the expression again.

Now, I can change the negation of "there exist" to "for all" by negating the inside of the brackets:
$\forall y \forall x (prime(2*x) \land prime(y) \land \neg (2*x=y*y))$

This, however, is not correct, but I can't find the mistake in my reasoning. I would really appreciate if someone could point me the right way. Thank you.

Comment: Why not express the condition of $x$ being even with $\exists z (x=2z)$ ? Maybe it is more easy to rea...

Comment: If so, IMO it is quite correct: $∀x∀y \ [prime(x) ∧ prime(y)∧ \exists z (x=2∗z) \to ¬(x=y∗y)]$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My last line does not have an implication, all it has are conjunctions. It's different from what you wrote.

Comment: I've said "quite"... :-)

Comment: When you move inside the negation sign switching $\exists$ to $\forall$, you arrive at $\lnot (P \land Q)$ that is equiv to $P \to \lnot Q$.

Comment: Your initial formula must be $¬∃x((prime(2∗x)∧prime(y)) ∧(2∗x=y∗y))$

Comment: Since $2$ is the only prime number that is even, $\mbox{prime}(2x)$ is true only when $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**There does not exist an even prime number which is the square of a prime number.**

First we should clarify what is meant by "[even prime number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvenPrime.html)". Below are two possible predicate definitions:

1. $\mbox{evenPrime}(x)\equiv x=2$
2. $\mbox{evenPrime}(x)\equiv (2\mid x\land\mbox{prime}(0.5 x))\lor x=2$

So now we can translate the above statement as the following
$$\forall x\lnot\exists y(\mbox{evenPrime}(y)\land \mbox{prime}(x)\land y=x^2)$$
If you apply the first definition of $\mbox{evenPrime}$, then the statement is true.

If you apply the second definition of $\mbox{evenPrime}$, then the statement is false.